# How do I show image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Hi I'm trying to create an application that can show the image by clicking a button. But, I want my image to be shown without using a Label. is that even possible if I don't use a label to show the image? Thankyou

Comment: you can use canvas

Comment: Why do you not want to use a label?

Comment: @BryanOakley if i try to show another image the first image disappear and the only thing that left is the label and it doesn't show the image

Comment: Please show an example of that.